# How to find values of variables for which $f(x)= x^3+3x^2+4x+b \sin x + c \cos x$ is one-one?

Tags: analysis, functions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, monotone-functions

I have a question that tells me to find the range of $b^2+c^2$ for which $$f(x)= x^3+3x^2+4x+b \sin x + c \cos x,$$ $\forall x \in R$ is one-one function.

****[The answer says that $b^2+c^2 \leq 1$]****

My book does this question as follows:

$f'(x) = 3x^2+6x+4+b \cos x -c \sin x$

Now, the book states that the ***only possibility*** for $f(x)$ to be one-one would be if $f'(x) \geq 0$, i.e, it is monotonically increasing. I have a doubt here. Why cant $f'(x) \leq 0$, i.e, a monotonically decreasing function also satisfy the criteria that the function would be one-one?

Why can the function only be monotonically increasing and not decreasing for all $x$ in R??? I know that that the parabola is upwards, from $f'(x)$, but depending upon b and c values, can't the derivative of $f(x)$ be negative? Why is it said for one-one function the only possibility is that the function is increasing?

Comment: $f(x)$ cannot be monotonically decreasing because $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$.

Comment: In other words, yes for some values of $b$ and $c$ you can have $f'<0$ at _some_ values of $x$, but because the parabola "is upwards", you can never have $f'<0$ at _all_ values of $x$.

Comment: @PeterForeman What does that imply, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Techie5879 How can the function increase from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ if it's decreasing?

Comment: @PeterForeman sorry, that was just stupid of me. I guess I'm just becoming dumber by the day. Thanks for your help. Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $$f'(x)=3x^2+6x+4+b\cos{x}-c\sin{x}\geq$$
$$\geq3(x+1)^2+1-\sqrt{(b^2+c^2)(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)}\geq1-\sqrt{b^2+c^2}.$$
We see that for $b^2+c^2\leq1$ we have $f(x)\geq0.$

From here easy to see that $b^2+c^2\leq1$ it's the condition for increasing.

$f$ can not be decreased because for any $a$ and $b$ we have:   $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$ and $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$$

Comment: This, I know. But my question was, why can't the function be monotonically decreasing. It isn't given that $b² +c²$ less than 1, but that's the answer.

Comment: I wanted to know why can't this be one-one if f is monotonically decreasing

Comment: The question is about one step in the proof, which you didn't discuss at all.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thanks

Comment: @Techie5879 You are welcome!